# Knockout Force notify subscribers of an observable when setting new value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Suppose we want to assign a new value to an observable and notify subscribers regardless of whether the new value equals or not to the old value.

By default, Knockout won't notify subscribers if the new value is the same as old one, so we need to take some extra steps to achieve our goal.

I know There is extender `currentPage.extend({ notify: 'always' })` but I need that behavior in a specific place only, not globally for an observable.

Currently, I'm using the following approach:

```
    // Some view model property of primitive type
    self.currentPage = ko.observable(1);

    // Some view model method
    self.foo = function (newPage) {
        var currentPageObservable = self.currentPage;

        // Save the old value
        var oldCurrentPageValue = currentPageObservable();

        // Update the observable with a new value
        currentPageObservable(newPage);

        if(oldCurrentPageValue === newPage) {
            // If old and new values are the same - notify subscribers manually
            currentPageObservable.valueHasMutated();
        }
    };
```

But that looks like it could be better.

**Why Knockout just doesn't provide, for instance, a method for assigning a new value to an observable that always notifies subscribers?** Or am I missing such one?
**And what are your approaches for achieving the same task?**

Comment: You can overwrite that observable's `equalityComparer` function to always `return false` (and later `delete` it, so it falls back to the original comparer).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach is good enough, except you may want to refactor it in order not to notify subscribers twice, when the value has changed.

```
if (oldCurrentPageValue !== newPage) {
   // Update the observable with a new value
   currentPageObservable(newPage);
}
else {
   // If old and new values are the same - notify subscribers manually
   currentPageObservable.valueHasMutated();       
}
```

In your case `currentPageObservable(newPage)` notifies subscribers and right after that `valueHasMutated` will notify subscribers second time.

Another approach would be extend `ko.observable` with specific methods

```
ko.myObservable = function Observable(initialValue) {
   var result = ko.observable(initialValue);
   result.updateWithNotification = function (newValue) {
      ...
   }
   return result;
}

var o = ko.myObservable();
o.updateWithNotification(newValue);
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain in which cases in my example subcribers would be notified twice? In my tests there is only single notification. It seems like for me that I only interfere in regular KO notification mechanism only in case of the new value is equal to old one,